# Radeon R7 250X OverClocked version; recommended power supply?

Tags: power-supply, amd-graphics-card

I have looked back and forward trying to find a PSU that fits that graphics card, because screen started flickering and system crashed if I used the graphics card mentioned above with a 500w PSU. I read somewhere I needed at least 430w (realhardtechx.com), then somewhere else 350w (power supply calculator), and some even went as low as 299w (some other power supply calculator). I have actually bought a 750w, and according to what I've looked at, it should be more than enough... But I am in serious doubt if it will even work.

So, question: is 750W enough, or what is enough for that?
NOTE: This is also my first build, so I am pretty nooby.

In case people are wondering, here's my setup (without the graphics card):
Motherboard: Asrock Z97
CPU: Intel i7-4790 - LGA1150
RAM: 2x8GB - 1600mhz - DDR3
PSU: Cooler Master B500 v.2
Storage: Some seagate 2TB SSHD.

Comment: you should just calculate total power consumption of your hardware (usually easy to see on the box) and add another 50w for good caution.

Comment: You have bought the 750 Watt power supply. Surely you can tell us? I'd be stunned if the answer wasn't "yeap, works fine".

Comment: Where exactly did you read you need 420W?

Comment: @Ramhound on realhardtechx.com. I see I was a tad bit wrong; twas 430w. But the one I am using is the OverClocked version. So I got no idea. Also, this is my first ever build, so I am kind of a noob.

Comment: Update your question to include that information and a link or quote what precisely you are talking about.

Comment: I can already tell you 750W will be more than enough. 750W will have  more than enough headroom. You could run your setup with another R7 250X off of that if you wanted.

Comment: Aye. Thanks! I will go with the 750w then. I'll update the title to say it's solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 430~530W PSU should be more than enough, I am running an i5 6600 and a R9 380 on a 530W PSU without any problems :P

Comment: Sorry for off topic, but since I'm actually about to buy an R9, how bad is the power consummation really? I have read ranges from 290W-340W while gaming., which seems a little bit to much for me..

Comment: The R9 series spaces from the 370 to the 390X, so there are very different power usages. My 380 uses around 180W~200W maximum when gaming in FHD. I generally set the fans to work al the time, so you could achieve a minor consumption with a 380 G1 gaming. Note that i overclock a bit, so the results may vary

Comment: Thank you very much! Thats exactly what I thought the whole time, it _could_ use that much, but it's unlikely, especially when playing FHD only. I will also go with a 390 than. Ty.